# Is there a for loop to check if they are all colliding ? Godot

Tags: collision-detection, godot, godot4

i have a node (FloorChecker-Node2D) and in that node i have 4 RayCast2D and im trying with a for loop to check if all children are colliding if yes set it too true if none of them are colliding set it to false. The problem im facing right now is if one child is not colliding it goes to false. Anyone knows how to fix that ? Thank you in advance.

Code im using:

```
for ray in floorChecker.get_children ():
        ray.force_raycast_update()
        if(ray.is_colliding()):
            touchingFloor = true;
        else:
            touchingFloor = false;
```

Comment: How about adding `break` after setting it to true? That exits the for loop, meaning no other child can overwrite that value.

Comment: Well it works for now but it needs more testing. Is there a way to check every raycast for itself in the for loop ?

Comment: Instead of a 'bool' you could increment an integer and check if it's greater than 0. (Don't forget to set the counter to 0 before the loop though)